# How to run Drush 10 custom command in Drupal 8 form submit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I have created a custom command for drush 10 in my drupal 8 setup. The command works fine from the terminal. However I want to run that command when the user clicks on form submit. I have tried using the below and I am getting the following errors

1.
`drush_invoke_process("@self", "my-custom-command");`

**Error**: `Call to undefined function drush_invoke_process()`

2.

```
$alias_manager = Drush::service('site.alias.manager');
Drush::drush($alias_manager->getSelf(), 'my-custom-command')->run();
```

**Error**: `Drush::$container is not initialized yet. \Drush::setContainer() must be called with a real container.`

Am i missing something? Are there any alternatives to execute a drush command programmatically?

Comment: Can you add detailed version of Drupal and Drush you are using?

Comment: @KienNguyen Drupal version : 8.9.11 and Drush Commandline Tool 10.3.6